# MySql #1243 error while executing it through phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to execute this code in phpMyAdmin. But, I'm getting following error

#1243 - Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE

```
    SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'count(distinct CASE WHEN topic = ''',
      topic,
      ''' THEN t2.id END) AS `',
      topic, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
(
  select count(distinct id) total, topic
  from table2 
  group by topic
  order by total desc
  limit 2
) d;

SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT t1.year, ', @sql, ' 
            from table1 t1
            left join table2 t2
              on t1.id = t2.id
            group by t1.year');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Check out [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66a44/1) for implementation.

How to fix this? Also, as a com-mentor mentioned this will work when sent through script. Any ideas how do I script in PHP?

Comment: Hi, 2 years in the future, any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

That is because the PMA doesn't use the same mysql session to execute the queries that's why you receive the error.

But if you were to execute this in a script using the same mysql function it should work.